# Sha256,Sha384,Sha512 is not working in WIndows XP?

Tags: vb.net, sha

this below code is worked fine in windows 8.1 and 10 and tested in
windows xp sp3 it's not working and return null value and also
same problem in sha1, sha384 but MD5 is working fine and get return output
but others could not,
 does windows xp sp3 support sha checksum functions
or need any special codes (sorry for poor english)

```
    Public Function GetSha512Hash()
    Dim _flexe$ = ""
    Dim _result$ = ""
    Try
        _flexe$ = IO.Path.Combine(Application.ExecutablePath)
        Using _sha512 As New System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512CryptoServiceProvider
            Using stream = File.OpenRead(_flexe$)
                Dim _hash = _sha512.ComputeHash(stream)
                _result$ = BitConverter.ToString(_hash).Replace("-", String.Empty)
                Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", _result$))
                Return _result$
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Trace.WriteLine(Err.Description)
        Me.PEx = ex
        Return _result$
    End Try
End Function

'SHa384
Public Function GetSha384Hash()
    Dim _flexe$ = ""
    Dim _result$ = ""
    Try
        _flexe$ = IO.Path.Combine(Application.ExecutablePath)
        Using _sha512 As New System.Security.Cryptography.SHA384CryptoServiceProvider
            Using stream = File.OpenRead(_flexe$)
                Dim _hash = _sha512.ComputeHash(stream)
                _result$ = BitConverter.ToString(_hash).Replace("-", String.Empty)
                Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", _result$))
                Return _result$
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Trace.WriteLine(Err.Description)
        Me.PEx = ex
        Return _result$
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: The classes in the Cryptography namespace that have "CryptoServiceProvider" in their name depend on a CAPI, an installable component provided by the operating system.  So not having it installed is the first basic failure mode.  XP also dates back to an era where the USA government put export restrictions on cryptographic software, giving only USA residents access to the more advanced ciphers.  SO users should complete their profile to get effective help.  Consider using the pure managed providers, like SHA512Managed.

Comment: thanks sir, so may i used  `If Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major <= 5 Then` used SHA1Managed else SHA1CryptoServiceProvider.. am i correct

Comment: Hard to guess, you have not explained at all why you prefer CSP and why it suddenly would be okay to not use it on an old machine.  It is not a random choice, some users demand usage of a certified algorithm.  Talk to your users.  Don't forget to mention the CAPI install requirement while you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading some documentation, it seems that windows XP SP3 cannot obtain certificates if it is encrypted using a sha256/384/512 encryption. ([Link](https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1499561-sha-256-compatibility))

Please be aware that Windows XP is [not](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsforbusiness/end-of-xp-support) longer supported by Microsoft, which means that developping for the platform might be [dangerous](https://www.wired.com/2017/05/still-use-windows-xp-prepare-worst/).

If you -do- want to continue with the development. You can try to the hotfix found on [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/968730/windows-server-2003-and-windows-xp-clients-cannot-obtain-certificates) page, which involves installing an official Microsoft dll, released in 2009.

Answer (score 0):

finally i got some information about [Difference between SHA1, SHA1CryptoServiceProvider, SHA1Managed and SHA1Cng classes in .NET](http://codeissue.com/issues/i34dda6deaad90a/difference-between-sha1-sha1cryptoserviceprovider-sha1managed-and-sha1cng)...

1. SHA1: this is abstract class. All other implementation of SHA1
   (SHA1CryptoServiceProvider, SHA1Managed and SHA1Cng) implements this
   abstract class. To create concreate SHA1 class, use SHA1.Create().
   By default SHA1.Create() returns SHA1CryptoServiceProvider, which is
   configurable. To configure default SHA1 implementation:
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/693aff9y.aspx
2. SHA1CryptoServiceProvider: this is wrapper for unmanaged
   CryptoAPI(CAPI). This is Federal Information Processing Standard
   (FIPS) certified.
3. SHA1Managed: this is complete implementation of SHA1 using managed
   code. This is fully managed but not FIPS certified and may be
   slower.
4. SHA1Cng: this is wrapper for unmanaged Cryptography Next Generation
   (CNG). These are newer implementation of cryptographic algorithms by
   Microsoft with Windows 2008/Windows Vista or newer. This is also
   FIPS certified.